# Mocking a function called by the function you are unit testing. using moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

For example you are testing `getSomeString`.

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1() {}

    public string getSomeString(string input)
    {
        //dosomething

        OtherClass class = new OtherClass();

        return class.getData();
    }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public OtherClass() {/*some data*/}    

    public string getData()
    {
        //do something

        string aString = getAString(Input);

        //do something
    }

    public virtual string getAString(string input);
    {
        //do something to be mocked
        return somethingToBeMocked;
    }
}
```

So you need the unit test to mock out `getAString`. How do you do this?

I have tried just mocking `getAString` and hoping the test uses the mocked value, but that doesn't work.

I have tried mocking `Class1` and setting the unit test `class1` to be the mocked object, but I could not figure out how to make the mocked `getAString` passed into the mocked `class1`.

I cannot figure out what to do.

Comment: What mocking tool are you trying to use?

Comment: Have you tried searching up how to do proper unit testing?

Comment: You have to do something about the `OtherClass class = new OtherClass();`. That is one dependency that `Class1` has. You need to make that more flexible. Consider "dependency injection" (search for that). Somehow `Class1` instances must be more flexible as to how they get their `OtherClass`, or the `OtherCLass` instance could be a parameter to the method `getSomeString`.

Comment: @Maess moq, i put it in tags but forgot to put it elsewhere

Answer (score 6):

You can't just take any code and unit test it. Code should be testable. What is testable code? It's a code which depends on abstractions instead of implementations. Only way to avoid depending on implementations is providing them via dependency injection:

```
public class Class1()
{
    private IOtherClass _otherClass; // depend on this abstraction

    public Class1(IOtherClass otherClass) // constructor injection
    {
        _otherClass = otherClass;
    }

    public string getSomeString(string input)
    {
        //dosomething
        return _otherClass.getData(); // you don't know implementation
    }
}
```

Where `IOtherClass` interface is implemented by `OtherClass`

```
public interface IOtherClass
{
     string getData();
}
```

Now your class depends on abstraction and you can mock abstraction for tests:

```
string data = "Foo";
Mock<IOtherClass> otherClassMock = new Mock<IOtherClass>();
otherClassMock.Setup(oc => oc.getData()).Returns(data);
var class1 = new Class1(otherClassMock.Object);
// Act
string result = class1.getSomeString("Bar");
// Assert
Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(data));
otherClassMock.VerifyAll(); // check dependency was called
```

Comment: Good answer. Technically it is possible in Moq to mock a class (as opposed to an interface), and the method in question was `virtual`, so it could be done without introducing the interface, but the interface is probably a good practice.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen agree, mocking class can have side effects because it have some implementation. On the other hand when you are mocking interface, you completely control results

Comment: So, for this, where would the normal implementation of getData be? and how would the non unit test code know to use the normal getData? (interfaces have always confused me for some reason)

Comment: The normal implementation of `getData` is in `OtherClass`. When you're testing your code, you use Moq to generate a mock implementation of `IOtherClass`. When you're not unit testing, you just pass a new instance of `OtherClass` into `Class1` via the constructor.

Comment: @DanielMann So basically you pass OtherClass into Class1 as a variable?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thats why it is virtual at the moment, I am mocking it for other tests. (mostly tests for 'getSomeString')

Comment: @lazyberezovsky It seems to me like you are using the interface as a way to pass in a custom function of getData(), Which I can do anyway by mocking OtherClass and passing the mock into getSomeString (by changing it to getSomeString(string input, OtherClass otherClass) ) without using interfaces.

Comment: @puser I'm using interface to keep `Class1` out of any knowledge about `getData()` implementation. Of course you can use parameter injection instead of constructor injection

Comment: To preserve the original code's behavior, I'd change the dependency to be a Func<OtherData> factory instead, which is called on every getSomeString invocation. I like creating interfaces for the dependencies, but it's not required as long as the classes have virtual members (I suggest using https://www.nuget.org/packages/virtuosity.fody to make that the default in your projects ;))

Answer (score 2):

The way you typically accomplish this is by coding to an interface and then injecting an implementation into the class you're trying to test.

In this case, your public API to `OtherClass` looks like it's really just one method: `getData()`. So, with that in mind:

```
public class Class1
{

    private IOtherClass otherClass;
    public Class1(IOtherClass otherClass) 
    {
        this.otherClass = otherClass;
    }

    public string getSomeString(string input)
    {
        return otherClass.getData();
    }
}

public interface IOtherClass 
{
    string getData();
}

public class OtherClass : IOtherClass
{

    public Otherclass() {/*some data*/}    

    public string getData()
    {
        //do something

        string aString = getAString(Input);

        //do something
    }

    private string getAString(string input);
    {
        //do something to be mocked
        return somethingToBeMocked;
    }
}
```

Then, when you wanted to mock, you create a fake implementation of `IOtherClass` and provide it to `Class1`.

I haven't used Moq for a while, but you should be able to do something like this in your test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Foo() 
{
    //Arrange
    var expected = "expectedResult";
    var mock = new Mock<IOtherClass>();
    var otherClass = mock.Setup(foo => foo.getData()).Returns("someValue");
    var myClass = new Class1(otherClass.Object);
    //Act
    var actual = myClass.getSomeString("something");
    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: No, getData has to be called properly, the //dosomethings are important. tbh, the name 'getdata' was a silly name to choose for my example. Also, getAString needs to be public as it is used elsewhere too

Comment: Why does `getData` have to be "called properly"? That's defeating the point of a unit test. The goal is to test the code in `Class1` in *isolation*, so you can verify its behavior without having to worry about how the code in `OtherClass` affects it.

Comment: I am not entirely sure why that is the common belief. Class1 calls other classes, so isolating Class1 you either leave in the other classes and use them as part of the test. OR you remove them and assume everything will all work when its all put together. both of these in my opinion are equally valid.

Comment: Oh, a question. How would you unit test a class/function that calls multiple other classes/funtions in it. And the functionality of it is based entirely how it interacts with other classes/funtions. Would you not bother testing, or would you say that the class/function is (almost certainly) incorrectly built?

Comment: interestingly, most people advocate for not testing private tests and testing them withing your public methods, which is the opposite of 'testing in isolation' (in a way)

Comment: @puser if class only interacts with other classes, then it's responsibility is managing other objects work. E.g. there is a person who neither write code nor do QA testing. But his responsibilities is giving tasks for developers and qa, and managing tasks progress. Would you say this person is incorrectly build? Same with classes

Comment: @puser sorry, didn't get why testing public methods is opposite to testing in isolation. How these two things can be related?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky oh, I didn't think the class was incorrectly built, I'm just bad at wording things. With a class that manages/uses other classes, how would you test it? (I'm just wondering what other people opinions are)

Comment: @puser in that case you should use interaction-based testing instead of state-based testing. That is what mocks was created for. Consider to read great Martin Fowler's article [Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) (sorry, I will be AFK for several hours, can answer your questions later)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Well, by 'testing in isolation' I thought daniel meant that if you had a method that called other methods, you want to not test the functionality of the called method, but only that method so to do this, you  mock out anything that the tested method calls. Unrelated to this, a lot of people say to not test private methods, and just whenever they are called by a public method, that is a good enough test. i.e. don't isolate the private methods. It wasn't a real point, merely an observation